# Controller scope value not updated via ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I just remove `ngRoute` for using `ui.router`.

My routeProvider became $state provider :

```
/*
$routeProvider.when('/login', {
  templateUrl: 'views/auth/connexion.html',
  controller: 'ConnexionCtrl'
});
*/
$stateProvider.state('app.auth', {
  url: '/auth',
  templateUrl: 'views/auth/connexion.html',
  controller: 'ConnexionCtrl'
});
```

And my `<div ng-view></div>` is now `<ui-view></ui-view>`.

In my ConnexionCtrl :

```
angular.module('angularApp')
  .controller('ConnexionCtrl', function ($scope, User, $location) {    
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
      console.log($scope.email);
    };
});
```

And the view is :

```
<div ui-view>
  <form role="form" name="connexion_form" ng-submit="submitForm()">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="xxx@xxx.xx" /><input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

When I submit my form, the `console.log` prints `undefined`. Why ng-model doesn't update my `$scope.email` ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are not providing correct email format, else the code looks fine.

Comment: There must be something in other parts of your code, because with what you have provided, the code should work properly

Comment: I found the problem ! If my form is in a `<div ui-view>` the $scope.email wont be updated, but I need to have it here. =(

Comment: You can specify `templateUrl` in your `$stateProvider` and have the template as partial. As a best practice, you shouldn't include html in your `ui-view`

Comment: But, if I have a substate : `state('app.auth.lost-password', {url: '/lost', templateUrl: 'views/auth/lost-password.html', controller: 'LostPasswordCtrl'})` The view isn't displayed when I click on the `<a ui-sref="app.auth.lost-password">`.

Comment: That is because you are mixing up the child - parent relationship. I bet you have a link within `templateUrl: 'views/auth/connexion.html'` refering to the lost password view and my guess is there is no container for it. You're expecting it to display in its parents container. (Id est: you have two siblings but you created a parent - child view relationship)